# Extracting Text from one cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am collecting requests for inventory items as text from a google form using the checkbox control.  When multiple items are selected, I end up with multiple text strings separated by a comma in one cell.  I need to be able to fulfill the inventory items requested and I want to parse out each text phrase so I can match it to my items, fulfill the request and update the inventory as gone.

I have a sheet with inventory items, concatenated to the text strings as items, updated the form checkbox values to present to the user and collect the form responses.  I need to be able to parse out when multiple choices are made, the response so I can match it to my inventory catalog, pick/pack it, and mark it off the list as fulfilled.

I'm using QUERY against my responses to pull out the date/time stamp as the key column, and the items selected as my text column.  I think I need a custom function (or run a a script) to parse out the items and return the index/row number of text back on my catalog sheet.  I'm just stuck on parsing out the multiple text blocks out of one cell.

Answer (score 1):

like james say, you need to split content, from app script you need.

1_getRange of content.

2_use **youRange.splitTextToColumns(',')**

3_get new Range .

good luck

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `SPLIT` might do the job for you: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en

It can separate text from one cell into an array of cells based on a delimiter of your choice. However, keep in mind that it might falsely split your items in half if any of them also have a comma in their name.